# TextView disappear when run app but it is visible in design mode

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, textview

[image: [Image]]

I have problem with my app. I want to add some text to it (TextView). As you can see in Preview i can see this text ("Wygrana"). But when I launch my app, there is no text anywhere. Can someone help me fix it? Part of code for TextView is on image.

Full main_activity.xml: https://codeshare.io/5wR4jP

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.tik_tak_toe

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.widget.Button


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Wygrana.setText("aaaaaa")
    klik(button1)
    klik(button2)
    klik(button3)
    klik(button4)
    klik(button5)
    klik(button6)
    klik(button7)
    klik(button8)
    klik(button9)
    Wygrana.setText("aaaaaa")

}
}
```

function "klik" is function which write text on button after clik. It works very well,and i have no problems with it

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/tlo">
    //buttons 
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Wygrana"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/wygrana"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your MainActivity.

Comment: post your activity_main.xml file code and MainActivity Code

Comment: Can you add code of activity_main.xml?

Comment: It's not full. According to your screenshot there's 2 `</LinearLayout>`

Comment: Full main_activity.xml is under this link https://codeshare.io/5wR4jP. 
I can't post there all code